# Google Chrome Help

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I want to make an extension that highlights a certain word (for example food) on every page the person visits. I was curious as how to do this, with a google chrome extension.

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to do this just using [content scripts](http://code.google.com/chrome/extensions/content_scripts.html). In your content script JS file, this line should do the trick (assuming you also include jQuery in your JS content script includes):

```
$('body').html($('body').html().replace(word_of_choice, '<span class="highlighted">' + word_of_choice + '</span>'));
```

And define the `highlighted` class in a CSS file in your content script includes.